# javascript function's parameter returning undefine

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function short_tag(tag, contents) {
  return "<" + tag + ">" + contents + "</" + tag + ">";
}
document.getElementById("test-2").innerHTML = short_tag(p, okok);
```

```html
<div id="test-2">

</div>
```

Does anyone know why does the error p is not defined is returning?

Comment: You haven't defined `p` or `okok`?

Comment: What do you mean i could've done that with php, anyways how can i define it?

Comment: `p` is a variable. `'p'` is a string. Is that where your confusion comes from…?

Comment: And… if you're doing the same thing in PHP, stop doing that and quote your strings. If you'd activate error reporting in PHP it too would be complaining about this, just not as loudly as Javascript.

Comment: to answer your comment question: `var p = 'my strin value'` but what you actually want to do is `short_tag('p', 'okok' )`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because p is  getting treated like a variable where as `p`  should be a String. Same with `okok`

```js
function short_tag(tag, contents) {
return "<" + tag + ">" + contents + "</" + tag + ">";
}
document.getElementById("test-2").innerHTML = short_tag("p", "okok");
```

```html
<div id="test-2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `p` and `okok` should be strings but are referenced as variables.

```js
function short_tag(tag, contents) {
    return "<" + tag + ">" + contents + "</" + tag + ">";
}
document.getElementById("test-2").innerHTML = short_tag('p', 'okok');
```

```html
<div id="test-2">
</div>
```

Comment: good practice , indent your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why does the error p is not defined is returning?

Because `p` is a variable name and you have not defined it.

You appear to be trying to pass the **string** `"p"`, so you should use a *string literal* and not a *variable name*. Put quotes around it.

Comment: `okok` also not defined